# GetListItems returns only open items

Tags: list-view-threshold

I'm using SharePoint 2010 SOAP interface with Perl.
Sometimes it is necessary to crawl through closed items and remove attachments,  but `GetListItems` returns only active items.

How to I get **all** items instead of only active ones?

Actual XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName xsi:type="xsd:string">DB8F7CAD-D459-46FD-82B8-5888A55C1EC2</listName>
            <rowLimit xsi:type="xsd:int">4999</rowLimit>
        </GetListItems>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post your SOAP Query?

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha please see my update

Comment: Maybe also pass the ViewName parameter to a View that contains all the items.

Comment: I tried to do so, but my main idea was to figure out how to get all items  only with list name, as there can not be a possibility to create special view (e.g. insufficient access privileges or so )

Comment: There should be a default "All Items" view that should contain all the documents. Why not pass that as the view name? Either way I think REST would work better in this scenario. "http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items"

Comment: There are some limitations which don't' allow me to use REST api, hence the only option at the moment  is to use view with all items. thank you.

Comment: Let me know how the All items view returns results.

Comment: with all items view everything works well.  the reason I tried to avoid using it,  is that this view is one more entity, which increases system's complexity, and, consequently, decreases reliability

Answer (score 0):

You havent set view, so make sure in default view you have not any filter but displayed all items otherwise you need to define view in this SOAP request.